# Hangman: How to compare and replace a dash with a letter found

Tags: java

I am learning Java, I know it exists several solutions on stackoverflow but I am stuck. I am trying to create a basic Hangman.

**I would like to know how Could I replace a dash with a letter found?**

Here is a demonstration:

The word to search is:`no`

1. I enter the letter `n`

```
You have 5 attempts.
--
Enter your letter: n
```

2. I enter the letter `o`

```
You have 4 attempts.
--
Enter your letter: o
```

3. Idem.

```
You have 3 attempts.
--
Enter your letter:
```

Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

char letter = 0; // declares and initialises letter
String[] words = {"yes", "no"}; // declares and initialises an array of words to guess
String word = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]; // chooses random word
boolean[] found = new boolean[word .length()];
int attempts = 5;

while(attempts > 0){
  System.out.println("You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
  for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
    if ( found[i] ) {
      System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }
    else {
      System.out.print('-');
    }
  }

  System.out.println("");
  System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
  letter = input.next().charAt(0);

  attempts--;
  }
```

I have to add a loop perhaps?

I share you my code here => https://repl.it/repls/PeriodicLegitimateMatrix

Comment: Use a debugger or print statements to check the values in `found` and you'll see the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [indexOf(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) method in the `String` class to check whether the character was in the word.

It should look like this:

```
while (attemps > 0) {
    //...
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
    letter = input.next().charAt(0);

    int characterPosition = word.indexOf(letter);//use a loop because the character could appear in more than one position in the word
    while (characterPosition != -1) {//if indexOf(char) returns -1 it means the char was not found
        found[characterPosition] = true;
        characterPosition = word.indexOf(letter, characterPosition);//this time search the character starting from the last position to find the next one
    }

    attempts--;
}
```

Comment: Note that `System.out.println("")` could be replaced by just `System.out.println()`.